# Are there different methods to send a http response?

Tags: http, request, httprequest, response, httpresponse

We all know that a http-request has a method (GET/POST/etc.). I want to know are there any specific methods to a http-response too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## NO.

The **method** is a property of an HTTP request message. It does not appear in the response message.

See [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230).

Answer (score 1):

While HTTP requests contain a *method* to indicate the semantics of the request, HTTP responses contain a *status code* to indicate the result of the operation.

See below some relevant quotes from the [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), the document that defines the message syntax for HTTP/1.1:

> [**3.1.  Start Line**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1)
>
> An HTTP message can be either a request from client to server or a response from server to client.  Syntactically, the two types of message differ only in the start-line, which is either a request-line (for requests) or a status-line (for responses) [...]

> [**3.1.1.  Request Line**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1)
>
> A request-line begins with a method token, followed by a single space (`SP`), the request-target, another single space (SP), the protocol version, and ends with `CRLF`.
>
> ```
> request-line   = method SP request-target SP HTTP-version CRLF
> ```
>
> The method token indicates the request method to be performed on the target resource.  The request method is case-sensitive.
>
> ```
> method         = token
> ```
>
> [...]

> [**3.1.2.  Status Line**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2)
>
> The first line of a response message is the status-line, consisting of the protocol version, a space (`SP`), the status code, another space, a possibly empty textual phrase describing the status code, and ending with `CRLF`.
>
> ```
> status-line = HTTP-version SP status-code SP reason-phrase CRLF
> ```
>
> The status-code element is a 3-digit integer code describing the result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the client's corresponding request. [...]
>
> ```
> status-code    = 3DIGIT
> ```
>
> [...]

Answer (score -1):

An HTTP response is made by a server to a client. The aim of the response is to provide the client with the resource it requested, or inform the client that the action it requested has been carried out; or else to inform the client that an error occurred in processing its request.
An HTTP response contains:

```
A status line.
A series of HTTP headers, or header fields.
A message body, which is usually needed.
```

As in a request message, each HTTP header is followed by a carriage return line feed (CRLF). After the last of the HTTP headers, an additional CRLF is used (to give an empty line), and then the message body begins.